I’ve changed username by sudo usermod now I can’t log in the user account
I was trying to change my username and searching in the internet I’ve found this command:
sudo usermod -l new_username -d /home/new_username previous_username
To apply the changes to all directories.
I ran the command from another user.
But now I can’t log in the principal user back. When I enter the password it keeps returning to the login screem.
How can I revert this miserable changing I’ve done? 

You've not mentioned what Ubuntu product/release you're using, It's likely you'd be able to login if a server install (you didn't specify), but with a test done here on a test system here, I'd not expect a GUI login to work, but your OS/release may differ to my system as you've not specified what you're asking about.

Can you log in as new_username? How about sudo -i? Does that get you a root shell?

You probably should have added the -m option to create the new home directory and copy the old user's files - iirc -d alone does neither, so unless you created /home/new_username graphical login is likely failing because there is no home dir. You should still be able to log in via a CLI virtual terminal (although it will complain and temporarily set the home directory to /).

... see for example How to make user home folder after account creation?
